# How to omit leading zeros (in years only) in Biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, citing

When I cite ancient and early medieval sources, years before 1000 are being prefixed with leading zeros by Biblatex. How can this be changed?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: **By default**   `0233` as  date field, or as year field, print just "(233)",  in both cases. Also just `233` work as year field.  The only problem is  that `233`  in a date field is an invalid date format, and therefore you must  add the left zero only to lost it in the output. If your document behaves differently, without a MWE, only you can know why the hell he does it.